# Python - How to find all same types of files in a folder and make a list out of it?

Tags: python, list, filenames

I've tried this code to find all the 'jpg' files in a folder and make a list out of it. But the result shows something like as below.

```
['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '8', '.', 'j', 'p', 'g']
['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '8', '.', 'j', 'p', 'g', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '4', '.', 'j', 'p', 'g']
```

It returns all the characters of the names of the files to list not the names of the files in a whole.
How do you solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
import os 

def find_names(outpath):
    root_path_list= [file for file in os.listdir(outpath)]
    jpg_file_list = []
    for idx, file in enumerate(root_path_list) :
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            jpg_file_list += file             
            print(jpg_file_list)
```

Comment: `jpg_file_list += file` does extend the list, so it add all elements of 'file' (all letters) , use `jpg_file_list.append(file)`

Comment: As an aside, your list comprehension `[file for file in os.listdir(outpath)]` does nothing - you could just assign `root_path_list = os.listdir(outpath)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use `glob` library :

One line can solve your problem :

```
import glob, os
glob.glob(os.path.join(outpath,"*.jpg"))
```

For your code , if you want to append element into a list, you must `+=` a list.

```
jpg_file_list += [file]
```

or use append

```
jpg_file_list.append(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
import os 

def find_names(outpath):
    return [file for file in os.listdir(outpath) if file.lower().endswith(".jpg")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob

files = [os.path.basename(i) for i in glob.glob('*.jpg')]
```

Note the extension is case sensitive, if you have files with a JPG extension you will need do some further work.

Answer (score 0):

Append the entry to the list

```
jpg_file_list.append(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have commented on ways of creating the list of file extension matches. They do not directly clarify what I believe is the other part of the answer to your question, why the individual letters are ending up in your jpg_file_list rather than the filename string.

One of the things that is touched on but not explicitly stated by the answers here is that a string (such as the filenames) is a type of collection.

That is useful so that you can iterate over the characters in the string, index into it and take slices of it. It can be a nuisance though in some cases when you're thinking of it as an item and the code treats it like a list.

In your code the filename string is being treated like a list not a single item and the characters are added into the list individually rather than the filename as a single entry.

As others have already said, to change your code to deal with the fact that strings are collections, you would need to change:

```
jpg_file_list += file
```

to

```
jpg_file_list += [file]
```

or

```
jpg_file_list.append(file)
```